# Subprocess with 'watch' command

Tags: python, subprocess

Is it possible to get the watch command in shell to work with subprocess?

```
tail = subprocess.Popen("watch -n 1 'tail -n 1 /mnt/syslog/**/*.log | grep :'", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Because it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Have you tried using `os.system(your_cmd)` to run your command?

Comment: What is not working? What is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Your subprocess command is correct, but after you assign stdout and stderr buffers you need to read from them. This is one way to do that:

```
#!/usr/env/python

import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ['watch', '-d', 'tail', '-n', '1', '/var/log/messages']

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(lambda: p.stdout.read(1), ''):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I have stated the command as a list argument. This is the way subprocess module recommends doing it. Then the for loop iterates over the buffer, reading 1 byte at a time and printing it to the screen. This stream will be closed once the subprocess dies or closes it.